# Permissions on nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Say that, a set of nodes and relationships has been created in neo4j db. Is it possible to restrict users from creating new nodes but allow them to add data to existing nodes and relationships. Also in relational dbs we can get the list of tables in the db by querying the system tables/objects, how do we achieve this in neo4j.

Comment: Thanks Kenny! for immediate reply, your answer was helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j, as of version 2.01, does not have the same authentication mechanisms as relational databases like MSSQL. Neo4j does not have tables, but I assume you are wanting to introspect the database, and in that case you can use the following query to see what is connected:

```
// What is related, and how
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
RETURN DISTINCT head(labels(a)) AS This, type(r) as To, head(labels(b)) AS That
LIMIT 100
```

This returns back a list of values showing you what is connected by label in the property graph.

As far as restricting users from creating new nodes but to allow them to update nodes, this is something you'll want to handle in your application code. Whatever authentication mechanism you are using in your application, make sure you handle authentication, roles, and permissions on your own.